# Different results in Codeblocks and Visual Studio 2015 when using cin.fail()

Tags: visual-studio-2015, codeblocks

so the problem is that when I compile and run the program in VS 2015 and I put in say a string as the first cin, it writes "Wrong input" just as I intended it to do. However, when I build and run it in codeblocks and I input a string as the first cin, the console starts spitting out consecutive natural numbers endlessly and I have no clue as to what is going on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


void printPrimes(int a, int b)
{
for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {

    int x = 1;
    for (int j = 2; j <= sqrt(i); j++)
     {
        double temp;
        temp = i % j;
        x++;
        if (temp == 0) break;
        else if (temp != 0 && x == floor(sqrt(i))) cout << i << endl;

    }

    }
}

int main()
{
cout << "Insert interval:" << endl;
int a, b;
cin >> a >> b;


if (cin.fail() || (a > b))
{
    cout << "Wrong input." << endl;
}

if (a < 0)
{
    a = 0;
}

printPrimes(a, b);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: I now know I missed return 0; in one of the conditions. I also know the code itself is garbage and it won't print all primes. But that's not the point, the point is why does it behave in different ways in VS and in CB.